# ASP.NET Core with JavaScriptServices - Failed to build project in VS 2017

Tags: reactjs, razor, asp.net-core

I am new to ASP.NET Core. I have used React before but I want to use it with ASP.NET Core now. so trying with JavaScriptServices in ASP.NET Core.

I have VS 2017 Community (as learning this by myself at home), .NET Core 1.1.2 runtime and .NET Core Sdk - 2.0.0 installed on my system.

I tried to create new project using "dotnet new reactredux" command and project is created in my directory.(Reference : https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/webdev/2017/02/14/building-single-page-applications-on-asp-net-core-with-javascriptservices/)

Now I am opening that project in VS 2017 but it fails to restore packages and build. it gives me many errors. One of the error I have mentioned below :

Package Microsoft.AspNetCore.Razor.Runtime 2.0.0 is not compatible with netcoreapp2.0 (.NETCoreApp,Version=v2.0). Package Microsoft.AspNetCore.Razor.Runtime 2.0.0 supports: netstandard2.0 (.NETStandard,Version=v2.0)

I am not sure whats going on and all errors are related to compatibility.
Any suggestions what I am doing wrong or missing ?

Comment: Is there a `global.json` file somewhere in the project/solution? If so, what version of the SDK is it using? I think it should be 2.0.0.

Comment: I dont have global.json as I am on .net core 1.1 and it gives .csproj file. I checked into that it uses 2.0.  Find info below :


<PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp2.0</TargetFramework>
    <TypeScriptCompileBlocked>true</TypeScriptCompileBlocked>
    <TypeScriptToolsVersion>Latest</TypeScriptToolsVersion>
    <IsPackable>false</IsPackable>
</PropertyGroup>

<ItemGroup>
   <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.All" Version="2.0.0" />
</ItemGroup>